# Porque no me calcula el resto de los inputs

Tags: javascript, datatables

Tengo una tabla y estoy calculando la diferencia de horas pero solo me calcula la primera fila de la tabla
Aqui mi codigo de javascript

```
 <script>
   //Creamos variables para recorrer fechas y agrupar total x día
    var afecha = new Array(); var fecha = ""; var i = 0; var firsttime = 1;
    var atotal = new Array(); var total = 0; var totaltotal = 0; var contartotal = 0; var multi =0;

  $(".td-calcular").each(function (){
     var HDesde = $(this).data("inicio");
     var HHasta = $(this).data("fin");

     //recoges el valor del día y en la primera entrada lo asignada a la var fecha
     var dia = $(this).data("dia");
     if (firsttime==1) { fecha = dia; firsttime = 0; }

     hora1 = (HDesde).split(":");
     hora2 = (HHasta).split(":");
     HoraDesde=(hora1[0]);
     MinutoDesde=(hora1[1]);
     HoraHasta=(hora2[0]);
     MinutoHasta=(hora2[1]);
     TotDesde=parseInt((HoraDesde*60)) + parseInt(MinutoDesde);
     TotHasta=parseInt(HoraHasta*60) + parseInt(MinutoHasta);
     RestaHoras=(TotHasta - TotDesde);
     TotHorasTrab=(RestaHoras / 60).toFixed(2);

     $(this).html(TotHorasTrab);

     //Ahora en el momento que cambies la fecha guardas los valores de fecha y total en dos arrays y pones total a 0
     if (fecha != dia) {
    afecha[i] = fecha;
    atotal[i] = total;
    i++;
    total = 0;
 }
 fecha = dia;
     //Incrementas total
     total = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(TotHorasTrab);

  });
  //Añadimos el valor del último día y mostramos resultados alamacenados en el aray
  afecha[i] = fecha;
  atotal[i] = total;
  for (j=0; j<afecha.length; j++) {
     $( ".div-calcular" ).data( "calcular", atotal[j]); 
      totaltotal+=atotal[j];

    }

    contartotal = afecha.length;
    multi = afecha.length*9;
    $('#totaltotal').html(totaltotal);
    $('#countTotal').html(contartotal+' dias  ['+multi+']');

</script>
```

mi tabla, me crea una tabla por cada día diferente.

```
 <?php if ($seguimientos): ?>
    <?php $fechas = array();
          foreach ($seguimientos as $seguimiento) {
             $fechas[$seguimiento-> fecha][] = $seguimiento;

          }
    ?>
    <?php foreach ($fechas as $fecha): ?>
    <table class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Fecha</th>
            <th>Orden</th>

        </tr>
    </thead>
    <?php   foreach ($fecha as $seguimiento): ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $seguimiento-> fecha; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $seguimiento-> horaInicio; ?>
      <input type="hidden" id="horaInicio" value=" echo $seguimiento-> horaInicio;">
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $seguimiento-> horaFin; ?>
    <input type="hidden" id="horaInicio" value=" echo $seguimiento-> horaFin;">
        </td>


    </tr>

    <?php endforeach; ?>
        </table>
      <div class="col-4 col-md-2">
              <h5> Total horas por fecha : <div class="div-calcular" data-calcular=""> </div> </h5>
              <h5> Horas turno :    9</h5>
              <h5> % Ocupacion por fecha: </h5>
            </div>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

 <div class="col-4 col-md-2">
      <h5>Total horas :  <p id="totalhrs" style="float:right;"></p>  </h5>
      <h5>Horas turno : <p id="countTotal" style="float:right;"></p> </h5>
      <h5>% Ocupacidad por fecha<p id="totalResultado" style="float:right;"></p> </h5>
            </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: es porque los ID deben ser únicos, por eso te toma el primero que encuentra

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Los ids deben ser únicos, puedes hacerlo por ejemplo asignando datos con el atributo `data` y recorriendo todos los tds donde quieres rellenar. Es modo de evitar crear inputs que no parecen formar parte de un formulario.

```
<?php foreach ($fecha as $seguimiento): ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <?php echo $seguimiento->fecha; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $seguimiento->horaInicio;?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $seguimiento->horaFin;?>
        </td>
        <td class="td-calcular" data-inicio="<?php echo $seguimiento->horaInicio;?>" data-fin="<?php echo $seguimiento->horaFin;?>" data-dia="<?php echo $seguimiento->fecha;?>" >    
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Y ahora recorres todas las casillas dónde necesitas calcular:

```
    //Creamos variables para recorrer fechas y agrupar total x día
    var afecha = new Array(); var fecha = ""; var i = 0; var firsttime = 1;
    var atotal = new Array(); var total = 0;

        $(".td-calcular").each(function (){
           var HDesde = $(this).data("inicio");
           var HHasta = $(this).data("fin");

           //recoges el valor del día y en la primera entrada lo asignada a la var fecha
           var dia = $(this).data("dia"); 
           if (firsttime==1) { fecha = dia; firsttime = 0; }

           hora1 = (HDesde).split(":");
           hora2 = (HHasta).split(":");
           HoraDesde=(hora1[0]);
           MinutoDesde=(hora1[1]);
           HoraHasta=(hora2[0]);
           MinutoHasta=(hora2[1]);
           TotDesde=parseInt((HoraDesde*60)) + parseInt(MinutoDesde);
           TotHasta=parseInt(HoraHasta*60) + parseInt(MinutoHasta);
           RestaHoras=(TotHasta - TotDesde);
           TotHorasTrab=(RestaHoras / 60).toFixed(2);

           $(this).html(TotHorasTrab);

           //Ahora en el momento que cambies la fecha guardas los valores de fecha y total en dos arrays y pones total a 0
           if (fecha != dia) {
          afecha[i] = fecha;
          atotal[i] = total;
          i++;
          total = 0;  
       }
       fecha = dia;
       //Incrementas total
       total = parseFloat(total) + parseFloat(TotHorasTrab);

        });
        //Añadimos el valor del último día y mostramos resultados alamacenados en el aray
    afecha[i] = fecha;
    atotal[i] = total;
    for (j=0; j<afecha.length; j++) {
        alert(afecha[j] + " - " + atotal[j]);
    }
```

Ahora tienes dos arrays, uno con fechas y otro con el acumulado por fecha en la misma posición que la fecha correspondiente. Este es un ejemplo para guardar los valores, si quieres mostrarlos por ejemplo en un input, en lugar de guardar los valores en el array los asignas como valor del input que corresponda.

Editado para Añadir total x día.

**Edición como mostrar total x día**

Una forma muy sencilla es dar a los campos como id la fecha a rellenar y rellenarlos al recorrer el array que guarda estos datos de suma por día.

html

```
<div style="border: 1px solid #444" class="div-calcular" id="<?php echo $seguimiento->fecha;?>"></div>
<div style="border: 1px solid #444" class="div-calcular" id="<?php echo $seguimiento->fecha;?>"></div>
```

Y en el script

```
for (j=0; j<afecha.length; j++) {
        var fecid = "#"+afecha[j];
        $(fecid).html(atotal[j]);
        alert(afecha[j] + " - " + atotal[j]);
    }
```

Comment: Funciona de maravilla, una consulta si quiero sumar el total de los resultados y mostrarlos como debería hacerlo?

Comment: Creas una variable antes del each y dentro del each (funciona tipo bucle) le sumas cada totHorasTrabajo, tras acabar el each tendrás el valor total.

Comment: Funciona para el total de las horas, pero yo creo una tabla dependiendo del dia y quiero sumar el resultado de ese dia. Espero haberme explicado bien.

Comment: Entonces puedes darle una clase por día y recorrer los datos por separado, o bien le añades a la celda un data-dia y sumas los resultados con igual data-dia.

Comment: Intentare hacerlo, no es mucho pedir una ayuda visual de lo que quieres decir. saludos

Comment: Lo he editado para añadir el cálculo por día, espero que te valga.

Comment: agradecido me suma bien el total  de la horas. pero hay la forma que me me sube los sub totales y el total de tablas creadas. adjuntare una foto.

Comment: @MoteCL habia un error en el javascript para los días, lo modifico con una solución ya comprobada, por si aun no lo tenías

Comment: La suma me la concatena en string `2018-02-12 - 02.505.00` disculpa mucho las molestias!

Comment: @MoteCL parsea a float las cantidades al incrementar el total para evitar que las concatene como string.

Comment: vale entiendo como puedo asigarle del valor `atotal[j];` a un data, lo debería poner dentro del foreach, me suma bien y me cuenta tambien. he editado el post. saludos

Comment: @MoteCL genial, entonces ya lo tienes :)

Comment: `$(".div-calcular").data("sub-total").html(atotal[j]);` deberia ser algo asi en el foreach?

Comment: $( ".div-calcular" ).data( ".div-calcular", atotal[j]); data es un atributo.

Comment: asi en el html `<div class="div-calcular" data-calcular="">  </div>`?

Comment: Si, para ese div lo pones asi $( ".div-calcular" ).data( "calcular", atotal[j]); . Ten en cuenta que el nombre del atributo data es lo que queda a la izquierda de 'data-'.

Comment: Lo puse así en el javascript he igual no me funciona :(

Comment: @MoteCL añadido ejemplo sencilo de como mostrar los valores acumulados por día, igualmente se puede hacer recorriendo la clase, pero con el id te evitas recorrer la clase con each.

Answer (score 2):

Como bien te han puesto en el comentario, los ids de los elementos son únicos y no se pueden repetir. En ese caso sólo coge el primer elemento con esa id.

Yo te recomendaría recorrer las tablas y sus elemento td he ir cogiendo los datos para hacer los cálculos. Ya que no veo bien como es la tabla te pongo un código que tendras que adaptar a tu html:

```
  var table = $("table tbody");

  table.each(function() {

      this.find('tr').each(function () {
          //Aquí tendrias que recuperar los datos y hacer los cálculos
            y añadirlo donde lo necesites
      });
 });
```

Comment: adjunte el codigo de la tabla,  si la fecha es diferente carga datos  pero en otra tabla.